# ¿Por qué LabelEncoder.classes_ devuelve las etiquetas de la última columna del marco de datos codificado?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de codificar un marco de datos pero necesito guardar las clases de objetivo para rastrearlas más tarde.

Sin embargo cuando busco para las clases del `LabelEncoder` con `LabelEncoder.classes_`, me da solamente las clases de la ultima columna.

Por ejemplo con la siguiente dataframe:

```py
>>>import numpy as np
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>length = 10
>>>df_test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,length,size=(length, 5)),columns = list('ABCDE'))
>>>df_test['D'] = ['D' + str(randrange(2)) for i in range(0,length)]
>>>df_test['E'] = ['E' + str(randrange(3)) for i in range(0,length)]
>>>df_test

    A   B   C   D   E
0   5   6   2   D1  E0
1   6   1   5   D0  E1
2   2   4   8   D0  E1
3   2   4   0   D1  E0
4   3   2   2   D1  E1
5   6   1   4   D0  E2
6   2   1   0   D0  E2
7   3   0   9   D1  E2
8   1   7   0   D1  E2
9   2   3   3   D0  E1
```

Cuando intento encodarla y separar los features del target, la columna D, con la siguiente funcion:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from random import randrange

def clean_df(df, target):
    ''' Clean a dataframe to get a dataframe ready to be sent to a DecisionTreeClassifier

        inputs:
            df: dataframe to clean
            target: column to predict
    '''            
    filtered_cols = [target]      
    le = LabelEncoder()

    # label encoding
    df = df.astype(str)
    X = df.apply(le.fit_transform)

    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    y = df[target]    #target column i.e price range
    return X, y, le
```

Me devuelve las columnas de `E`:

```py
array(['E0', 'E1', 'E2'], dtype=object)
```

Sé, gracias a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31939145/4764604), que ahora hay probablemente metodos mas recientes como OneHotEncoder, aun no lo he dominado.

Answer (score 0):

LabelEncoder.classes_ devuelve las etiquetas de la última columna porque se invoca "fit" de nuevo para cada columna.

Es similar a lo siguiente:

```
for columna in df_test:
    le.fit(columna) #olvida las columnas previas
    df_test[columna] = le.transform(columna)
```

Si quieres almacenar todas las clases, debes usar distintas LabelEncoders para cada columna:

```py
def clean_df(df, target):
    ''' Clean a dataframe to get a dataframe ready to be sent to a DecisionTreeClassifier

        inputs:
            df: dataframe to clean
            target: column to predict
    '''            
    filtered_cols = [target]
    label_encoders = {colname:LabelEncoder() for colname in df}

    # label encoding
    df = df.astype(str)
    for i in df:
        print(i)
        df[i] = label_encoders[i].fit_transform(df[i])

    # split into input (X) and output (y) variables
    y = df[target]    #target column i.e price range
    return df, y, label_encoders

X, y, label_encoders = clean_df(df_test, "D")

for colname, label_encoder in zip(X, label_encoders):
    print(colname + ":", label_encoders.classes_)
```

Entonces, se invoca "fit" solo una vez para cada LabelEncoder, y no se pierde nada.

```
A: ['0' '2' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8']
B: ['0' '1' '2' '4' '5' '8']
C: ['1' '2' '4' '5' '8' '9']
D: ['D0' 'D1']
E: ['E0' 'E1' 'E2']
```

Recomiendo que uses `pd.get_dummies`:

```py
>>>pd.get_dummies(df_test)
   A  B  C  D_D0  D_D1  E_E0  E_E1  E_E2
0  2  5  6     0     1     0     0     1
1  8  7  3     0     1     0     0     1
2  7  5  4     1     0     0     1     0
3  1  6  6     0     1     0     0     1
4  7  4  9     1     0     1     0     0
5  9  1  9     0     1     0     1     0
6  7  3  4     1     0     1     0     0
7  8  1  6     1     0     1     0     0
8  9  0  0     1     0     1     0     0
9  5  0  8     0     1     0     0     1
```

Puedes especificar las columnas afectadas:

```py
>>>pd.get_dummies(df_test,columns=["D"])
   A  B  C   E  D_D0  D_D1
0  2  5  6  E2     0     1
1  8  7  3  E2     0     1
2  7  5  4  E1     1     0
3  1  6  6  E2     0     1
4  7  4  9  E0     1     0
5  9  1  9  E1     0     1
6  7  3  4  E0     1     0
7  8  1  6  E0     1     0
8  9  0  0  E0     1     0
9  5  0  8  E2     0     1
```